# how can I tell when the scroll-bar is at a certain height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

How can I tell when the scroll bar is at a certain height meaning when there is a certain amount of space between the top of the scroll-bar and the top of the scroll-bar's track?

And then execute JQuery code if that is a certain value.

Let's say when the space between the scroll-bar's too and the scroll-bar's track's top is 50% of the current viewport height then alert that "50% has been reached".

Answer (score 1):

element is particular div, tag or body  you want to check.

*element***.scrollTop** - is the pixels hidden in top due to the scroll. With no scroll its value is 0.

*element***.scrollHeight** - is the pixels of the whole div.

*element***.clientHeight** - is the pixels that you see in your browser.

```
var a  =  element.scrollTop  ;
```

will be the position.

```
var b  =  element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight  ;
```

will be the **maximum** value for *scrollTop*.

```
var c  =  (a / b)*100  ;
```

will be the percent of scroll *[from 0 to 100]*.